# Threading - how to improve the performance of App

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I am making a app which scans the list of songs from phone storage and store them in `ListView`. So, I created the class `SongsManager` which scans the songs from SD card and store them in `Array`.The code is given below.

```
public class SongsManager {
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() .getPath() + "/";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";
private File directory;

// Constructor
 public SongsManager() {
 }

/** * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in * ArrayList * */

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
            System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
            if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
                File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
                File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
                if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                    for (File file : listFiles) {
                        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            scanDirectory(file);
                        } else {
                            addSongToList(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    return songsList;
}


private void scanDirectory(final File directory) {
            if (directory != null) {
                File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
                if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                    for (File file : listFiles) {
                        if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            scanDirectory(file);
                        } else {
                            addSongToList(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }


private void addSongToList(File song) {
    if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
        HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        songMap.put("songTitle", song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
        songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

        // Adding each song to SongList
        songsList.add(songMap);
    }
}
 }
```

When I run the app, app freezes for 2 or 3 seconds due to fetching songs from SD Card. When I open the logcat, it shows the error **`The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`**. So, I decided to improve the performance of application. I modified the class as following

```
 public class SongsManager {

final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() .getPath() + "/";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";
private File directory;

// Constructor
 public SongsManager() {
 }

/** * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in * ArrayList * */

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
            System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
            if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
                File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
                File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
                if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                    for (File file : listFiles) {
                        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            scanDirectory(file);
                        } else {
                            addSongToList(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    return songsList;
}


private void scanDirectory(final File directory) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (directory != null) {
                File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
                if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                    for (File file : listFiles) {
                        if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            scanDirectory(file);
                        } else {
                            addSongToList(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
}


private void addSongToList(File song) {
    if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
        HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        songMap.put("songTitle", song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
        songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

        // Adding each song to SongList
        songsList.add(songMap);
    }
}
}
```

After modifying the code, freezing problem solves but the fetching of songs not working properly. When I open the app, some songs are loaded and some are not. When I reopen the app, some more songs are loaded. This problem is occuring. 
Here is my `Tab1 Class` code

```
public class Tab1 extends ListFragment {

private ListView lv;
// Songs list
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
    // get all songs from sdcard
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

    // looping through playlist
    for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsListData.add(song);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), songsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String[]{"songTitle"}, new int[]{
            R.id.songTitle});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return V;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show, where you call `getPlayList()`?

Comment: Added ... Please review .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using a `AsyncTask` instead of above implementation.. in your implementation there is no way to guarantee that all songs have been scanned after your `plm.getPlaylist()` is completed as it being done on several different threads. That's why you are not seeing all songs.

```
public class GetSongsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Hashmap<String, String>>> {
private final SongsManager mSongsManager;

public interface SongsReceivedListener {
    void onSongsReceived(List<HashMap<String, String>> songs);
}

private SongsReceivedListener mSongsReceivedListener;

public GetSongsAsyncTask(SongsReceivedListener mSongsReceivedListener) {
    this.mSongsReceivedListener = mSongsReceivedListener;
    mSongsManager = new SongsManager();
}

@Override
protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void.. voids) {
    return mSongsManager.getPLayList();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> v) {
    if(mSongsReceivedListener != null) {
        mSongsReceivedListener.onSongsReceived(v);
    }
}
}
```

Where your list fragment will implement `SongsReceivedListener` and call this AsyncTask like this

```
new GetSongsAsyncTask(this).execute();
```

your `ListFragment` will look like this

public class Tab1 extends ListFragment implements GetSongsAsyncTask.SongsReceivedListener{

private ListView lv;
// Songs list
public ArrayList> songsList = new ArrayList>();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    new GetSongsAsyncTask(this).execute(); 
    return V;
}

@Override
void onSongsReceived(List<Hashmap<String, String>> songs) {
  if(getContext() == null)
   return;
  // looping through playlist
  for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
      // creating new HashMap
      HashMap<String, String> song = songs.get(i);
      // adding HashList to ArrayList
      songsListData.add(song);
  }

  // Adding menuItems to ListView
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), songsListData,
          R.layout.playlist_item, new String[]{"songTitle"}, new int[]{
          R.id.songTitle});
  setListAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Comment: @AkshaySharma thats what I have done. Let me try to add more details

Comment: @AkshaySharma added more implementation

Comment: Thanks Sir . . Please wait ... I will try and get back to you. Thanks again

Comment: @AkshaySharma you should use first implementation of `SongsManager` the one without threads with `AsyncTask` here